# TSQL - Getting the row number which failed during merge operation

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I am using sql server and I have a SQL query which merges a #tempEmployee table to the main employee table and then I drop the tempEmployee table.

In some cases, when any of the rows fails to merge due to some constraint etc then I want to track that row so that I can fix the error cause and again start the merge operation.

I am doing this for inserting bulk data to the employee table. I create the #tempEmployee table in C# and then send this #tempEmployee table to sql server to merge with the main employee table.

For eg:-

```
MERGE INTO Employee T 
USING #TempTable Temp ON T.businessentityid = temp.businessentityid 
WHEN MATCHED 
   THEN 
UPDATE SET T.BusinessEntityID = temp.BusinessEntityID
   ,T.DepartmentID = temp.DepartmentID
   ,T.ShiftID = temp.ShiftID
   ,T.StartDate = temp.StartDate
   ,T.EndDate = temp.EndDate
   ,T.ModifiedDate = temp.ModifiedDate 
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
  THEN 
INSERT(BusinessEntityID,DepartmentID,ShiftID,StartDate,EndDate,ModifiedDate)
VALUES( temp.BusinessEntityID, temp.DepartmentID, temp.ShiftID, 
temp.StartDate, temp.EndDate, temp.ModifiedDate)
```

My question is that is there a way to know which row got failed during the merge operation?

Comment: can you plese post your merge code here?

Comment: I don't have time to test right now, but shouldn't the existence of a failed record fail the entire bulk?

Comment: Yes, It should fail the entire bulk but my question is that I want tract that row due to which my bulk got failed so that next time I can correct that and start the bulk job again

Comment: Nothing in built in tsql does this but this article on merge error handling - http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/MERGE/71396/ - details a technique for capturing and identifying error rows

Answer (score 1):

If "which row got failed during the merge operation" is rows that don't match, you can use OUTPUT clause:

```
MERGE INTO Employee T 
USING #TempTable Temp ON T.businessentityid = temp.businessentityid 
WHEN MATCHED 
   THEN UPDATE 
        SET T.BusinessEntityID = temp.BusinessEntityID
           ,T.DepartmentID = temp.DepartmentID
           ,T.ShiftID = temp.ShiftID
           ,T.StartDate = temp.StartDate
           ,T.EndDate = temp.EndDate
           ,T.ModifiedDate = temp.ModifiedDate 
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
  THEN INSERT(BusinessEntityID,DepartmentID,ShiftID,StartDate,EndDate,ModifiedDate)
        VALUES( temp.BusinessEntityID, temp.DepartmentID, temp.ShiftID, temp.StartDate, temp.EndDate, temp.ModifiedDate)
        OUTPUT inserted.* into ***some table***
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql